# Watir-Webdriver throwing Unknown Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir for some automation. I want to select a value from select list so I did--
    `$browser.select_list(:id,"id_of_select_list").select("text")`

this, but this is giving me error as

```
`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: '[JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file:"file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20131118-31369-q5lb08/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js" line: 7677}]' when calling method: [nsICommandProcessor::execute]`
```

This error interestingly comes only in case of firefox, when I use chrome everything works fine.
Any thoughts...

Comment: What version of Selenium? What version of Firefox?

Comment: Is it just a plain select list? Perhaps sharing the html of the select list would help.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this 
xyz_select_list= $browser.select_list(:id,"id_of_select_list").wait_until_present
xyz_select_list.click